# Airflow: Google Cloud Composer: TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm using MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator as below.

**Dag Task Details**

```
def gen_export_table_task(table_config):
    export_task = MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(task_id='export_dag_run_to_gcs',
                                                    dag=dag,
                                                    sql='SELECT * FROM dag_run LIMIT 10',
                                                    bucket='gs://aca-composer-bq-test-vishesh',
                                                    filename="cloudsql_to_bigquery_file.json",
                                                    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='google_cloud_storage_default',
                                                    mysql_conn_id='airflow_db')
    return export_task
```

***Please find below the Errror Details that i am getting while executing the DAG:***

```
[2019-12-19 11:32:29,649] {models.py:1796} ERROR - Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models.py", line 1659, in _run_raw_tas
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/mysql_to_gcs.py", line 106, in execut
    files_to_upload = self._write_local_data_files(cursor
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/mysql_to_gcs.py", line 153, in _write_local_data_file
    s = json.dumps(row_dict
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dump
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encod
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencod
    return _iterencode(o, 0
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in defaul
    o.__class__.__name__
TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializabl
```

Comment: Hey can you please post all the code for that DAG?

Comment: Having this issue too!